# render not defined in php

Tags: php, html, reactjs

I'm a beginner in html and react. I make front -end in this project. I don 't know why he said Uncaught ReferenceError: render_partner is not defined
    at partner:1570

index.blade.php

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div id="role">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var test = {
   name: 'Partners',
   url: 'partners',
   order: [{
                field: 'id',
                direction: 'desc'
            }],
   fields: [
    //{
     //field_name: 'reference_id',
     //display_name: 'numero de référence',
     //type: 'select'
    //},
    {
     field_name: 'lastupdate',
     display_name: 'dernière mise à jour',
     type: 'date',
     index:false
    },
    //{
    // field_name: 'dataconfirm',
    // display_name: 'data confirmé',
    // type: 'boolean',
    // index:false
    //},
    {
     field_name: 'businesspartnersname',
     display_name: 'nom du partner',
     type: 'text'
    },
    {
     field_name: 'legalform_id',
     display_name: 'statut legal',
     type: 'select',
     source:{
      url: 'legalforms.select'
     }
    },
    {
     field_name: 'globallocationnumber',
     display_name: 'globallocationnumber',
     type: 'integer',
     index:false
    },
    {
     field_name: 'street',
     display_name: 'Nom de la rue',
     type: 'text',
     index:false
    },
    {
     field_name: 'streetnumber',
     display_name: 'Numero de la rue',
     type: 'text',
     index:false
    },
    {
     field_name: 'box',
     display_name: 'Nom de la boite',
     type: 'text',
     index:false
    },
    {
     field_name: 'address2',
     display_name: 'Seconde addresse',
     type: 'text',
     index:false
    },
    {
     field_name: 'zipcode',
     display_name: 'code postal',
     type: 'text',
     index:false
    },
    {
     field_name: 'state',
     display_name: 'Ville',
     type: 'text',
     index:false
    }
   ]
  };
  var role = false;  
  //render_resource(test, $('#role').get()[0]);
        render_partner(test, $('#role').get()[0]);
    </script>
 <Button onClick=this.refs.partner.render_partner()>myButton</Button>
 <script href="../component/partner" ></script>
@endsection
```

partner.jsx

```html
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {HashRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {ResourceRetriever, Requests} from './retriever.jsx'
import {TableDefault, TableEdit} from './table.jsx'
import {LinkButton} from './button.jsx'
import Form from './form.jsx'
import {MainLayout, HeaderLayout, BodyLayout} from './layouts.jsx'
import route from 'ziggy'
import { Ziggy } from 'ziggy'
import {render} from 'react-dom'

const OnlineSubPartner = PartnerRetriever(TableEdit)

class Partner extends React.Component {

render() {
  let routes = {
            index: "/",
            create: "/create",
            edit: "/edit/:id"
        }
        let count=0
        let name =""
        if (this.props.count !== undefined || this.props.count) {
            count=Object.keys(this.props.data).length
            name = this.props.name + " (# = " + count + ")"
        } else {
            name = this.props.name
        }
        //console.log("phh1 resource props = ", this.props)
        
        return (
            <Router>
                <MainLayout>
                    <HeaderLayout name={name}>
                        <Route path={routes.index}
                               exact
                               render={() => (
                                    this.props.readonly ? 
                                    null :  
                                    <LinkButton to={routes.create}
                                                className="btn-primary pull-right"
                                                style={{marginTop: '-10px', marginBottom: '5px'}}
                                                label="Ajouter" />)} />
                    </HeaderLayout>
                    <BodyLayout>
                        <Route path={routes.index}
                               exact
                               render={() => <TableDefault {...this.props}
                                                           openEditRoute={(data) => "edit/" + data.id}
                                                           openPrintRoute={(data) => "print/" + data.id} />} />
                        <Route path={routes.create}
                               render={() => <Form {...this.props}
                                                   closeRoute={routes.index}
                                                   submitRequest={data => this.props.requests.store(data)}
                                                   closeOnSave
                                                   data={{}} />} />
                        <Route path={routes.edit}
                               render={(props) => {
                                            let data = this.props.data.filter((row) => row.id == props.match.params.id)[0]
                                            return (
                                                <div>
                                                    <Form {...this.props}
                                                          closeRoute={routes.index}
                                                          submitRequest={this.props.requests.update}
                                                          closeOnSave={this.props.subpartner ? false : true}
                                                          data={data} />
                                                    {this.props.subpartner && <OnlineSubPartner {...this.props.subpartner}
                                                                                                  id={data.id} parenturl={this.props.url} />}
                                                </div>
                                            )}} />
                    </BodyLayout>
                </MainLayout>
            </Router>
        )

}
} 

Partner.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  readonly: PropTypes.bool,
  requests: PropTypes.instanceOf(Requests).isRequired,
  data: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
  subpartner: PropTypes.object
}

export default function render_partner(partner, mp, subpartner) {
 const OnlinePartner = PartnerRetriever(Partner)
    ReactDOM.render(<OnlinePartner {...partner} subpartner={subpartner} />, mp)
```

rend_resource work with a another jsx that i take to make this. I think the problem is in the jsx with the sub and the partner but i don't see where

Comment: do a search through your code for `function render_partner`

Comment: Search "render_partner" (5 hits in 3 files)
C:\xampp\htdocs\mydibelportal\resources\js\components\partner.jsx
Line 91: export default function render_partner(partner, mp, subpartner) {
C:\xampp\htdocs\mydibelportal\resources\views\partner\index.blade.php (2 hits)
 Line 159       render_partner(test, $('#role').get()[0]);
Line 161 <Button onClick=this.refs.partner.render_partner()>myButton</Button>

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\mydibelportal\storage\framework\views\85f52e2840495f79db0f93657a18f623cdd1fb98.php
 Line 157       render_partner(test, $('#role').get()[0]);
Line 159: < <Button onClick=this.refs.partner.render_partner()>myButton</Button>

Comment: add a `<script src="/path/to/the/partner.js" type="text/javascript" />` somewhere

Comment: thanks to help me. I make it and i get a new error
GET http://www.mydibelportall.be/path/to/the/partner.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: use the real path to the JS file and not the placeholder i gave you LOL

Comment: GET http://www.mydibelportall.be/resources/js/components/partner.jsx net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
he don't find it

Comment: and if a write "C:\xampp\htdocs\mydibelportal/resources/js/components/partner.jsx"
I get the error Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/mydibelportal/resources/js/components/partner.jsx

Comment: what folder is your index.php in?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\mydibelportal\resources\views\partner\index.blade.php

Comment: thats a view script, I mean the index.php that bootstrap's your application. Usually in a folder called public?

Comment: i don't have index.php in public folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the import in app.js